# schedule GPU jobs in Matlab

Tags: matlab, gpu, jobs

I want to schedule 10 instances of a GPU-heavy script, using 10 different input parameters:

```
task1 = createTask(job1, @myscript, 0, {{1}, {2}, ... {10}})
```

I only have one GPU device and each script occupies it whole, therefore I would like the tasks to be executed one by one. How can I do this?
An ugly workaround that I use now is to set parpool size to 1 and have 10 different jobs with one task each.

A second question, is that if I run my GPU script from Matlab's command line, it executes correctly, but if I launch it as a job using parallel pool, I get an error:

```
An unexpected error occurred during CUDA execution. The CUDA error was:
                       all CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable
```

Comment: ehm... Why dont you just make an .m file with 10 calls to your function, one after the other? You can not parpool a GPU job, that makes no sense. A GPU job is paralel per se, and a single job will take the whole GPU power. Makes absolutely no sense to  break the GPU to do 10 different things at the same time.

Comment: The execution time is very long and I want to be able to use the Matlab client to analyse the results as they become available. If I run an .m file, Matlab's interface becomes blocked and I need to open a second Matlab to do the analysis.

Comment: Still, its an absolute misunderstanding on how GPUs work to think you can have a single GPU and run multiple jobs on it.

Comment: That is why my question asks on how to limit the number of tasks to one

Comment: I'd write a .m file and execute MATLAB in command mode, so it wont take any extra unecesary memory. You can then open a graphic instance of MATLAB to do whatever.